# How to get Range of Pan/Tilt/Zoom in PTZ Cameras?

Tags: camera, ip-camera

I have to write APIs for Panasonic WV-SC385 Network IP Camera. I searched a lot for getting Ranges of Pan/tilt/zoom, But I did not find any useful material. I will appreciate if somebody here provides me cgi command lists for WV-SC385. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to requests the API from Panasonic, as far as I remember they had developer portal and they do have these APIs documented. Another option is to use network sniffer to intercept and identify those commands and then check camera's web server JavaScript code in order to see the ranges of interest.